# How to identify which button is clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know , how it is able to identify, which button is clicked, if i have 3 buttons.

Thanks & regards

Comment: by click event........

Comment: Different Buttons have different `Button_Click` Events...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. but I need some other way to identify this

Comment: Why do you want this, please specify your requirements.

Comment: Requirement is like, in my application 3 actions are  there ,( Button), i would to save 3 different values based on the clicks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about your program, other than it having 3 buttons. So, here are our buttons:

```
Button b1 = new Button();
b1.Name = b1.Text = "Button 1";
Button b2 = new Button();
b2.Name = b2.Text = "Button 2";
Button b3 = new Button();
b3.Name = b3.Text = "Button 3";
```

Now each button needs to open a messagebox displaying their name when clicked. This is where we're going to use `Button_Click` event. Each button's `Click` event can have an unique method which is being called when the button is clicked, or all the buttons can use the same method. I'll provide you with both ways.

---

**Method 1: Same method for each button.** This method is going to do nothing but display the pressed button's name.

```
private void Global_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((Button)sender).Name + " was pressed!");
}
```

Whenever a button is clicked, this method gets called and the button is given as `object sender` parameter. Notice that we must cast it to `(Button)sender` before using it as a button.

There's still one thing to do. This doesn't get called automatically for each button, it's just a method. Instead, we must tell our buttons to call this when they're clicked. This is what events are for:

```
b1.Click += Global_Button_Click;
b2.Click += Global_Button_Click;
b3.Click += Global_Button_Click;
```

---

**Method 2: Unique method for each button.** This method is only required if your buttons do more than just print the name of the button. So, if the button click needs to do something unique for different buttons, use this.

It works the same as method one, but instead of defining one method for all buttons, we define 3 methods, one for each.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Button 1 was pressed!");
    // here you can add more code which will be executed when button 1 is clicked
}

private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Button 2 was pressed!");
    // code for button 2
}

private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Button 3 was pressed!");
    // code for button 3
}
```

Now lastly we need to tell the buttons to use these methods when they're clicked, and again we use events. This time, different method for each button:

```
b1.Click += Button1_Click;
b2.Click += Button2_Click;
b3.Click += Button3_Click;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.Is there any other way around?

Comment: @Anjana No. But using the first method is only 6 lines of code: 3 lines for method and 3 lines for telling the buttons to use `Global_Button_Click` method when they're clicked. Why would you need an other way?

Comment: @Anjana This is the only proper way, and it's the best for sure. Thanks for accept.

Comment: @ Markus Meskaen. Where will we include this code <code> b1.Click += Global_Button_Click;
b2.Click += Global_Button_Click;
b3.Click += Global_Button_Click;</code>

Comment: @Anjana Anywhere it fits. Maybe your form's constructor, load event or `InitializeComponent()`-method. Just make sure it's executed when your form opens.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the buttons have seperate event handlers but in case you have three buttons sharing the same event handler, then use command name/command arguments to differentiate between them. The event handler will have an CommandEventArgs through which you can collect the command names and command arguments

Comment: Thanks for the comment Mr Sasidhar